# AngularJS - Inject $factory into controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-controller

I have multiple factories registered, say `Circle`, `Square` and `Triangle`, and a controller called `ShapeController`. Inside of `ShapeController`, I'm trying to retrieve one of the factories using its string representation, in the same that I can fetch a controller using `$controller('ControllerName', {...})`.

```js
var ShapeController = function($scope, $routeParams, $factory) {
  var shape = $factory('Circle', []);  // shape is an instance of the Circle factory
  ....
}
```

I was hoping I could inject `$factory` but I keep getting `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $factoryProvider <- $factory <- ShapeController`. Is there any api or some way I could retrieve the factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you got it wrong. Actually there is nothing called as `$factory` inbuilt service/provider inside angularjs framework. The thing you mentioned about [`$controller`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$controllerProvider), its a special provider created by angularjs to instantiate a controller with some local (there you could mock dependencies as well).

As you wanted to grab the instance of particular dependency, you could extract it out from `injector`(this acts like DI container of DI system), where you should inject `$injector` dependency inside your controller factory function and use `get` method to retrieve particular dependency.

```
var ShapeController = function($scope, $routeParams, $injector) {
  var shape = $injector.get('Circle');
  ....
}
```

Comment: Wow bless you this is exactly what I've been looking for all along

Comment: @TheGirrafish I'm glad that it helped you, Thanks :)